# Difference in survival probabilities at a set timepoint from Kaplan-Meier estimator?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

I have a simple survival problem from an RCT, whereby there are two treatment groups (A-control and B-intervention), and the primary outcome is overall survival. We can estimate the Kaplan-Meier estimator and confidence bands using the Greenwood method. We are interested in survival at two years. How can we estimate the absolute risk difference (with confidence intervals) at 2 years? We are working in R and Stata, but this is not necessarily a software question.

Comment: It seems you already know your problem! In R, this question on StackOverflow answers your question on how to calculate risk differences of two K-M curves with confidence bands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714902/comparing-survival-at-specific-time-points